# draw a line over a plot in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect

I have a plot which is drawn in my `PlotView` class. This class is inherited from `CPTGraphHostingView`.

I wanted to draw a line **OVER** the plot. I want to move this line up and down by touching. The line should have something like an arrow in its beginning, so it is not simply a line (i.e. using an extra axis as a line does not solve the problem).

I wrote this code in PlotView class, which draws a sample line (I can add an arrow by drawing to it, it is no problem):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f); //start at this point

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20.0f, 20.0f); //draw to this point

    // and now draw the Path!
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

But apparently after I call this :

```
[plotController viewWillAppear:false];
```

(`plotController` being an instance of `PlotController`) I cannot call

```
[plotController setNeedsDisplay];
```

[image]

Any suggestion how to draw this line?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` class doesn't have a method setNeedsDisplay. The `UIView` class does have this method. So you can write like that:

```
[plotController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: thanks. I can call setNeedsDisplay now, but still I don't see any thing on the plot. Could it be that it is drawn under the back background?

Comment: if you have subview above the view on which you are drawing line then its under whole plot. Try drawing line on subview. and calling drawrect of subview